# Jquery clone/remove - adding elements to output

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have clone/remove functionality on a div and it's elements. This part is working ok but I have a generate code button and I need to output the contents of the newly cloned elements when these are generated.

At the moment I have the current javascript for outputting the original div elements on the page but I am wondering if there's a way of appending output on the fly based on whether div has been cloned or removed.

```js
var cloneIndex = $(".clonedInput").length;

function clone() {
  $(this).parents(".clonedInput").clone()
    .appendTo("body")
    .attr("id", "clonedInput" + cloneIndex)
    .on('click', 'button.clone', clone)
    .on('click', 'button.remove', remove);
  cloneIndex++;
}

function remove() {
  $(this).parents(".clonedInput").remove();
}

$("button.clone").on("click", clone);
$("button.remove").on("click", remove);

/*generate the code*/
function myFunction() {

  var quote = '"';

  var mobile_start = "<pre>&lt;div class=" + quote + "show-for-small-only" + quote + "&gt;</pre>";
  var inner_style = "<pre>&lt;hr style=" + quote + "color:#EEECE8; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px;" + quote + "/&gt;</pre>";
  var mobile_title = document.getElementById("title_text").value;
  var headline = "<pre>&lt;p class=" + quote + "text-center" + quote + " style=" + quote + "background-color:" + document.getElementById("name_text").value + "; color: white; font-size:45px; font-family:din-bold; padding-top:15px; padding-bottom: 10px;" + quote + "&gt;</pre>" + mobile_title + "<pre>&lt;/p&gt;</pre>";
  var mobile_end = "<pre>&lt;/div&gt;</pre>";

  document.getElementById("top").innerHTML = mobile_start + inner_style + mobile_title + headline + mobile_end + "<br /><br />";

}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 10px;
}

.clonedInput {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #def;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.clonedInput div {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="clonedInput" class="clonedInput">
  <div>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Product </legend>
      <label for="name">Title:</label>
      <input type="text" id="title_text" />
      <label for="mail">Product Name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="name_text" />
    </fieldset>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <button class="clone">Clone</button>
    <button class="remove">Remove</button>
  </div>
</div>
<button onClick="myFunction()">Generate Code</button>
<p id="top" style="font-family:Arial; font-size: 18px;"></p>
```

Comment: hard to understand the question. Also not good practice to mix unobtrusive event listeners (like your jQuery ones) and inline ones. Pick one approach and be consistent

Answer (score 0):

Use class names instead of IDs for the fields. When you're generating the output, loop through each `clonedInput` and select the fields within their children, like:

```
function myFunction() {
    var code = "";
    $(".clonedInput").each(function() {
        var title=$(this).find(".title_text").val(),
            productName=$(this).find(".name_text").val();
        code += ....... //append the code for each element
    });
    $("#top").html(code);
}
```

Tip: Use proper, descriptive, names for your functions, variables and element names.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gabriel.

Comment: Please consider marking it as the solution if it was helpful. Thank you.